# jquery function stops working after adding div

Tags: php, jquery, html

K I'm having some issues. I need to get the below to work. I'm very new to jquery/php but I have a drag and drop thats dragging into sortable-list. However the below is not working.. 
The  before "group" is called "squad".
The call is below

```
echo "<p><input type=\"submit\" class=\"input-button\" id=\"btn-add\" value=\"Add Squad\" /></p>";
```

Then I have the function written as:

```
$(function(){
        var count = 2;  
        $('#btn-add').click(function(){
            if(count == 5){
               $('.groupA').append('<div class="groupB"><div class="column left" style="color: darkorange;"><input  type="text" name="S' +count+ '" value="Squad ' +count+ '" style="text-align: center; width:151;"></center><ul class="sortable-list"></ul></div>');

               if(count > 11){
                  $('#btn-add').hide();
               } 
            } else if(count == 9){
                $('.groupB').append('<div class="groupC"><div class="column left" style="color: darkorange;"><input  type="text" name="S' +count+ '" value="Squad ' +count+ '" style="text-align: center; width:151;"></center><ul class="sortable-list"></ul></div>');
            }else {
               if(count > 11){
                  $('#btn-add').hide();
               } 
                if (count > 9)
                    $('.groupC').append('<div class="column left" style="color: darkorange;"><input  type="text" name="S' +count+ '" value="Squad ' +count+ '" style="text-align: center; width:151;"></center><ul class="sortable-list"></ul></div>');
                else if (count > 4)
                    $('.groupB').append('<div class="column left" style="color: darkorange;"><input  type="text" name="S' +count+ '" value="Squad ' +count+ '" style="text-align: center; width:151;"></center><ul class="sortable-list"></ul></div>');
                else 
                    $('.groupA').append('<div class="column left" style="color: darkorange;"><input  type="text" name="S' +count+ '" value="Squad ' +count+ '" style="text-align: center; width:151;"></center><ul class="sortable-list"></ul></div>');
            }
            count++;
        });
    });
```

Now I have edited this as Felix fixed my initial issue but now that I have the div fixed, all of my drag and drop is not working anymore. I have manually put one in via php and the drag and drop works for that one, but the ones created using the add button don't work. What am I missing?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here:

```
$(function(){
    var count = 1;  
    $('body').on('click','#btn-add', function() {
        // Your code here
    });
});
```

You also need to use `$('.groups')` instead of `$('groups')`

Comment: Felix, Turns out all my issues were just the $('.groups') Thank you. But it has created a new issue in that the drag and drop function doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way around the jquery drag and drop not working. after adding a DIV. However. I found that if I added all the divs and hid them all, and then used a jquery button to unhide them. That this actually worked, and there were no more bugs/issues. I hope this helps someone else looking for the same answers.